# Javascript OCR tesseract.js Error in copying number after recognition

Tags: javascript, tesseract, tesseract.js

i'm working on this project the idea of it is that you give the program an image and using OCR in javascript the program well detect or (recognize) a string or a word for example ('رقم العداد')
and copies the the number or the integer after the string with ( spaces ) like ==>>

```
7038842  رقم العداد
```

and that is it so i'm using Tesseract.js ( Tesseract.recognize ) to recognize the string but at the first i faced an Error

> Uncaught (in promise)

Erorr so after beating around the bush its turned out that the tesseract fail to detect some Arabic letters as they are so i print all the text detected from the image and it turend out that the string ['نقطة الخدمة'] is recognized as ['ننطة الخدمة'] and ['رقم العداد'] as ['رم العداد'] so using

> string.match method
> to maniplate and copy the number after the word the number was given for ['رم العداد'] was correct and clear but !!! for some reason the code is not copying the number written after the word ['ننطة الخدمة'] i tried to play around like adding spaces and tabs but the same problem is given so eventually i decieded to ask for some help so what is i'm missing

the code :-

```
<script>
        Tesseract.recognize(
        'form.png',
        'ara',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
    console.log(text);
    const info = ['ننطة الخدمة','رم العداد','القراءة'];
    for(k=0;k<info.length;k++){
    var result = text.match(new RegExp(info[0] + '\\s+(\\w+)'))[1]; /* info[0] the index of ['نقطة الخدمة']*/
    alert(result);
}

})
    </script>
```

the project image:-

[image]

Comment: Tesseract isn't particularly good at OCR compared with modern solutions. The text needs to follow a certain format, use particular fonts, and, even then, the failure rate is kind of high relative to today's other OCR AI. Because of this, there will be the need for a lot of manual intervention.

Comment: @Ouroborus can you give me an advice which other OCR another solution using javascript and thanks

Comment: @Ouroborus I really need your help